# не отображаются русские буквы в pandas IPython и Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, кодировка, pandas, кириллица

здравствуйте.
прошу подсказать.
ввожу

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\1.csv',encoding='utf-8')
```

и после

```
df.head()
```

выводит крякозябры
как это исправить?

Comment: какая версия Python используется? И в какой кодировке сохранен `1.csv`?

Comment: версия Python 2.7, кодировка в 1.csv- кириллица.

Comment: @impregis: "кириллица" это не кодировка (это ближе к набору символов, который можно представлять в самых разных кодировках). Примеры кодировки это utf-8, cp1251, cp866, utf-16, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATE:** ваш "CSV" файл является XLSX файлом на самом деле:

```
In [122]: pd.read_excel(r'D:\download\1.csv').loc[:1]
Out[122]:
                              Дата покупки  Сумма заказа, $              Адрес покупателя Категория товара  Unnamed: 4 Unnamed: 5  \
0  Fri Jun 03 2016 17:15:15 GMT+0000 (UTC)              4.0   Обл. Ростовский Р-он д., RU             Часы         NaN        NaN
1                                      NaN              NaN                           NaN              NaN         NaN        NaN

  Unnamed: 6
0        NaN
1        NaN
```

---

Попробуйте другие кодировки:

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\1.csv',encoding='cp1251')
```

или

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\1.csv',encoding='cp866')
```

Comment: перепробовал все какие есть кодировки поставить -все те же крякозябры.

Comment: попробуйте залить пример файла куда-нибудь, чтобы можно было воспроизвести проблему...

Comment: может я плохо ищу, но неужели никто не пытался открывать csv с русскими буквами внутри. там таблица с наименованиями позиций на русском

Comment: @impregis, я делал это много-много раз, но у меня не возникало таких проблем... Что вы видите если открыть этот файл, скажем в `Notepad++`?

Comment: если открыть в Notepad++ -все те же крякозябры, если открыть в excel- ругается, но открывает нормально.

Comment: ссылка на файл http://my-files.ru/xd87uf

Comment: внутри архив с csv и xlsx(с таким же содержанием) и сам файл notebook

Comment: @impregis, на самом деле - это "XLSX" файл - смотрите ответ...

Comment: спасибо большое за помощь!:)

Comment: буду знать теперь,спасибо!ответ принял.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте библиотеку Codecs:

```py
import codecs 

file = codecs.open('путь к файлу', encodind='cp866')
```